# How to use a Visual Studio Generator in cmake without installing Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2017, generator

I am using cmake to generate visual studio project and build it. I am using the following command on my local machine on which visual studio is installed and works fine:

```
cmake.exe -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" $(CMAKE_ARGS)
```

However, I cannot install visual studio on my build server and therefore the above command will fail. During the build I can copy as many files as I want on my build server but I just cannot install anything during the build. Is there anyway to do this without installing VS?

I came across the following cmake argument;

```
CMAKE_GENERATOR_INSTANCE
```

which seems to be pointing to the instance of the generator. I was wondering if I could copy the necessary files to my build machine and have this variable point to it in order to generate? Is this how it works? if not, is there a way to generate VS projects using cmake without installing visual studio on the build machine?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need entire IDE for installing that generator, but you still need Visual Studio Installer for "Visual Studio Build Tools":

- Go to https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
- Scroll down to the "All downloads"
- Select "Tools for Visual Studio"
- In revealed window download "Build Tools for Visual Studio 2022"
- Perform installation of required components